# How do I can confirm if the following is a high standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation

If a dataset has a mean of 17 and a standard deviation of 6, is this a particularly high standard deviation from the norm? And if so, why?

I have a looked at a few of the similar threads here where users have had similar problems however I have not been able to work out how to apply the answers to this example.

I am not a statistician myself but need to make an assumption about some data that has been given to me.

Comment: See this http://staff.argyll.epsb.ca/jreed/math30p/statistics/standardDeviation.htm

Comment: I'm no expert statistics, but what matters is that it is normal distributed, which means the data is fit by a family of curves, which one is just a matter of coefficients. So it seems to me you are going about it wrong.

Comment: @Kanwaljit Singh the asker seems to be asking about the spread of the distribution, rather then about how a single data point fits, or the probability of it. I think anyways? Perhaps there is some other normally disributed data which is tighter or one S.d. is $2$ instead of $6$. Then this distribution would appear spread out more, and the single S.d. higher. Seems to me there should be a plain different approach or more structured question. As it stands the answer is ambiguous, in one case it could be high and another, low given the information. Completely arbitrary and un-answerable.